# Issues Understanding & Implementing MVVM

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

As a novice and being self taught, I need help trying to understand the how-to's of implementing of MVVM model. I have read around on beginner guides, all of which largely make sense when I read them, but I can't seem to make the leap and implement this into my project.
I get that the core concept is to separate the data/model from the UI/View via the use of the viewmodel, yet I can't seem to hit that point of understanding which lets me go and do it myself.

In a nutshell, my project in its current state has a class called `Game` which has a number of dictionaries to store other classes that are named; `Bonus`,`Item` and `Unit`. There is typically only one instance of `game` being passed around, which gets serialized out to a file for saving the data, and deserialized back in.
Instances of `Unit` will have `string Name`, as well as `Dictionary<string,Item> AvailableItems`, and `Dictionary<string,Bonus> GrantedBonus` to represent the items and bonuses it has (if any).
Instances of `Item` has fields for `string Name`, `string Type` and `Dictionary<string,Bonus> GrantedBonus` to represent the bonuses conferred by this item (if any).
Instances of `Bonus` has fields for `string Name`, `string Effect` and `Dictionary<string,Bonus> SubBonus` to represent if this bonus also confers another bonus.
For the `Bonus` class, I have implemented the PropertyChanged notifications, and added the relevant properties for these fields. I have not done this for the others yet

All classes are populated with data provided by the user. When they start, Some `Bonus`'s have to be set up, before they are able to set up any `Item`'s, which have to be set up before any `Unit`'s can be set up, which have to be set up before the `Game` can be used further in the program. As each particular class is setup by the user, they will be added to their respective dictionary in the `Game`.
My understanding is that these classes are my Model's. I have a rough idea of what I want the view to look like, but I'm not going set this up yet as it might pollute the viewmodel design. Where I'm really having trouble, is trying to understand how to design the relevant ViewModels, even for the most simple of the classes `Bonus`.
At its most detailed level, typically when setting it up, the user will need to see the `Name` and `Effect` data, as well as the list of `SubBonus`'s, if it is populated. However, in most cases, the user will only ever need to see the `Name`'s of overall list of `Bonus` items, in list form, that is stored in the `Game` class.

Can I please get some guidance on how to construct the ViewModel class? Do I need to create one for the Bonus, ie `BonusViewModel`, or just the Game, since it ultimately is holding all the data? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Really depends on how you design your code. I prefer to use POCOs for my models and put all the INPC and other logic in my viewmodel.
e.g.

Model

```
public class Bonus
{
    public string Name { get; set;}
}
```

ViewModel

```
public class BonusViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    // ViewModelBase is an abstract class that implements INPC
    public BonusViewModel(Bonus model)
    {
        Model = model;
    }
    public Model Bonus { get; private set; }

    public string Name 
    {
        get { return Model.Name; }
        set { Model.Name = value; OnPropertyChanged("Name");}
    }

    public string FunnyName
    {
        get { return string.Format("{0} is so funny", Name); }
    }
}
```

View

```
...

<TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Name}" />

<TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=FunnyName}" />

...
```

Comment: if I understand what you've done correctly. The 'model' simply holds the data - no validation, methods for adding/removing etc.  the ViewModel is simply another class that takes the Model in its constructor, and has methods to retrieve the data contained within it. I assume validation etc would take place here too. Would I then be populating the dictionaries with the viewmodels instead of the models?

Comment: Yup, except the viewmodel doesn't have to take the model as its constructor. You could have an empty constructor and set the model externally. Depending on how you prefer to do your validation, it could either be done when user clicks on a save button, or you could do it in the "setter" part of the viewmodel properties. It is also possible to work with data annotations.

Comment: I don't bind dictionaries to the view. I bind to an ObservableCollection<T>.

Comment: +1. Wasn't quite the answer that got me over the line, but pushed me in the right direction.